# Save facebook connect profile picture to own server

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working in an application which uses facebook connect to fetch a user’s profile picture. But after the connection is made I still have to be able to crop and resize the “large” image. Therefor I want to download the profile picture from the facebook server to my own server.

As of now I am not able to download the picture to my server. Here is what I am doing:

1. The facebook profile picture get sync in our application from facebook with the following path http://graph.facebook.com/uid/picture?type=large
2. Now we need the image to be get saved locally from the URL mentioned above
3. Crop it and display it, but we are unable to save the image from the provided URL

**Question**

•   So how we can save the facebook profile picture in our server using this path http://graph.facebook.com/uid/picture?type=large?
•   Or what is the other solution to save facebook profile? Picture to be save in our server first before displaying it?
•   How do we still keep it in sync with facebook if we use the saved picture?

Then I have another question:
How do you delete the cookies for a once established facebook connect connections if a user does not want to use facebook connect no more?
If have tried to do this with the following code but no results:

```
    var api_key = "135xxxxxxxxxxx";
    var channel_path = ""+2;
    FB.init(api_key , cookie:false, channel_path, { "ifUserConnected": update_user_box });
    Function update_user_box(){
    Var fbId=FB.Connect.get_loggedInUser();
```

The code given above to delete the false cookie is not working. What do I have to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: You should create a separate question about deleting the cookie since it's not related to this one.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of saving all the profile photos you could display the photo in a div that is too small for the entire image. Basically let the html do the cropping.

```
<body>
     <div style="background-image: url(http://scm-l3.technorati.com/11/01/14/25023/facebook-logo.jpg); width: 380px; height: 300px;">
 </div>
</body>
```

OR, per my comments below, you could wrap an image and resize the div. Both options work. One avoids using a CSS url() which might not follow redirects in come rare cases.

```
<body>
     <div style="width: 380px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
         <img src="http://scm-l3.technorati.com/11/01/14/25023/facebook-logo.jpg" alt="Facebook" />
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I am ussing the same concept in my own application,but this is not working

Comment: its possible that the css url() doesn't follow the redirect. In that case you can just wrap an image with a div. I'll edit to add that option.

Answer (score 2):

Like [OffBySome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265570/offbysome) said [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732676/save-facebook-connect-profile-picture-to-own-server/6742483#6742483), the key is knowing that it will redirect you.  So, we turn off following the redirect automatically and retrieve the actual URL of the picture from the header of the profile URL.  Here's a snippet I've used to download the actual image file.  Available as a gist here: https://gist.github.com/1092990

```
private static final String PROFILE_PICTURE_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large&access_token=%s";

private String downloadFacebookProfilePicture(String uid, String accessToken, String username) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    //Get the picture url
    HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
    String profilePictureUrlString = new URL(String.format(PROFILE_PICTURE_URL, uid, accessToken)).openConnection().getHeaderField(
            "location");

    //Set up temp location for picture
    String fileExtension = StringUtils.substring(profilePictureUrlString,
            StringUtils.lastIndexOf(profilePictureUrlString, ".") + 1);

    String tempFilePath = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(System
            .getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"))))
            .append(StringUtils.replace(username, ".", "_")).append(".")
            .append(fileExtension).toString();

    String exportUrl = profilePictureUrlString;
        //Download file to temp  location
        downloadFile(exportUrl, tempFilePath);

    return tempFilePath;
}

private void downloadFile(String exportUrl, String filepath)
        throws IOException, MalformedURLException {
    InputStream inStream = new URL(exportUrl).openStream();
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
    copyStreams(inStream, outStream);
}

private void copyStreams(InputStream inStream, OutputStream outStream)
        throws IOException {
    try {
        int c;
        while ((c = inStream.read()) != -1) {
            outStream.write(c);
        }
    } finally {
        if (inStream != null) {
            inStream.close();
        }
        if (outStream != null) {
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably split your questions into separate questions but as [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732676/save-facebook-connect-profile-picture-to-own-server/6750757#6750757) have [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732676/save-facebook-connect-profile-picture-to-own-server/6742483#6742483), https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture will return a [302 redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) to the image URL that you can save to your server so you'll need to make sure you're either following the redirect or reading the Location header (more on how to do that [here](http://zzz.rezo.net/HowTo-Expand-Short-URLs.html)) to get the URI of the actual image.

As for your question on how to make sure you are always using the most up to date picture, you should subscribe to the "/picture" connection of the "User" object using [Real-time Updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) and we will ping your callback whenever any user of your app updates their picture so you can go pull the latest one. This way you won't have to keep polling to see if the user has changed their picture.

If you're able to achieve what you're going for with just CSS (without caching the pic on your own server), check out [squinlan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732676/save-facebook-connect-profile-picture-to-own-server/6738870#6738870).

Answer (score 1):

When you try to download the image, make sure whatever you are download the image with can follow 302 redirects because the graph Facebook link only returns a redirect to the image, not the actual image itself.  But cropping the image with CSS would make a lot more sense.

Comment: I am using facebook api in java application .please suggest any other solution

Comment: when i connect with facebook connect button.it redircts to facebook login page.Then sync image shown in own application.I want that the syn image should save in our own server so that we can use for that image for cropping.Any Idea ?

Comment: because we are letting the user crop the image with the following plugin http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/ the image needs to be downloaded and css cropping is not an option. Therefor I am still trying to download the profile picture. Any other ideas and could you elaborate on the 308 redirects.

Comment: URL u = new URL(CropImagePath);
String filePath = request.getParameter("CropImagePath");
String extention = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("."));
String path = request.getSession(false).getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(path);
sb.append(IConstants.UPLOAD_FOLDER).append("/").append(name);
File dir = new File(sb.toString());
if (!dir.exists() || !dir.isDirectory()) {
dir.mkdirs();
}if (dir.exists()) {
sb.append("/").append(name).append(extention);

Comment: try
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(u);
int width = (image.getWidth()) / 18;
int height = (image.getHeight()) / 12;
if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
BufferedImage out = image.getSubimage(x1,y1,w ,h);
ImageIO.write(out, "jpg", new File(sb.toString()));

Comment: Here CropImagePath is the path given by facebook (https://graph.facebook.com/[UID]/picture?type=large") from where we can read the image as compared by the curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/[UID]/picture?type=large");

Next line(String extention = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("."));) gives the extension of the file read from the"CropImagePath" path

than we need need to create the directory locally with particular id to store the image of particular log in user after convert the "\\" to "/"

Comment: After that the image is to read in the buffer from the url and read its height, width
  BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(u);
    int width = (image.getWidth()) / 18;
     int height = (image.getHeight()) / 12;

Now we need to crop the image if the image hieght width is greater than zero, so
 BufferedImage out = image.getSubimage(x1, y1, w, h);
     ImageIO.write(out, "jpg", new File(sb.toString()));

Comment: But now we are unable to save the image locally in the directory created earlier
 ImageIO.write(out, "jpg", new File(sb.toString()));

Comment: But now we are unable to save the image in our own server in the directory created earlier
    ImageIO.write(out, "jpg", new File(sb.toString()));    


The code is same as written in curl php
Could you please elaborate? What i have to do to resolve this issue

Comment: But now we are unable to save the image locally in the directory created earlier
 ImageIO.write(out, "jpg", new File(sb.toString()));